# What Kind Of Macro Is this?

Tags: c++, c

I came across this following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define d(x) x(#x[3])
int main(){
d(putchar);
}
```

Which prints `c` as the output. I wonder what does the macro `#define d(x) x(#x[3])` does? In C language is there an operator like `#`? I can see this inside the macro body i.e here `x(#x[3])`. According to my normal eye it looks something different I see in C language but actually What does this does?

**Edit :** Whats the real use of `#` in real world?

I'm a novice in C and it will be good if the explanation is in simple terms. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `#` is solely a preprocessor feature, not a C language feature.

Comment: Refer to [`string-izing` tokens in this link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html).

Comment: +1 - that would have caught me off-guard too, haha.

Comment: today i understood ;) why the first person answering getting so many upvotes :P

Comment: _where_ did you find this macro?  I can't think of a single valid use case other than illustrating how strange the preprocessor can be.

Comment: @AShelly see http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1091/whats-my-name-produce-the-name-of-the-language-indirectly

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The character '#' is a stringizer -- it turns a symbol into a string. The code becomes

putchar("putchar"[3]);

Comment: quickest answer i have ever seen :)

Comment: wait! `putchar("putchar"[3]);` is this valid? Please be clear I'm a novice in C! What this actually does?

Comment: C basic strings are char arrays, "putchar" is an array where item[0]='p',item[1]='u',item[2]='t',item[3]='c', etc..., that's why "putchar"[3] is 'c'

Comment: @Ant's: `"putchar"[3]` is equal to the character at offset `3` (starting from zero of course) in the string (which is just an array of `char`), so that’s why you get `"c"`.

Comment: @JonPurdy : any real world use of `#` ;)

Comment: @Ant's: Consider an `assert(x)` macro that asserts the expression `x` is true, and prints `#x` with `__LINE__` and fails otherwise.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Seems that you have read C very well :) thanks that was an good example :D

Answer (score 2):

The hash sign means "stringify", so `d(x)` expands to `putchar("putchar"[3])`, whence the `c`.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/):

Function macro definitions accept two special operators (# and ##) in the replacement sequence:
If the operator # is used before a parameter is used in the replacement sequence, that parameter is replaced by a string literal (as if it were enclosed between double quotes)

```
#define str(x) #x
cout << str(test);
```

Put simply, it changes the "x" parameter into a string.  In this case test becomes a char array containing 't', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'.

Comment: To be precise, test becomes "test", which is an array of five characters, the four letters plus the null character at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The `#` is a pre-processor operator which turns a literal into a string. In fact your `d` macro prints the fourth `char` of the converted string of your literal.

Comment: Bit of a cruel down vote... but the d macro actually passes the __4th__ character of its argument to the function named by its argument. d (james) would not print 'm' as your answer suggests (unless of course, james was a function whose effect was to print 'm' ;-))